# Edit and submit embedded PDF in Edge

Tags: html, pdf, microsoft-edge

I would like for my small website to display a PDF and let the user edit it and save it directly back to the server.

Edge has this neat inbuild PDF editor, that I am calling like this:

```
<embed 
  src="{{ invoiceAttachment.file.url }}"
  width="100%"
  height="2000px"
  type="application/pdf"
\>
```

[image]

This works like a charm. The PDF shows and users can edit, write, highlight and so on. However, when the user clicks on the inbuild save button, Edge triggers a Download. Rather than having the user store it locally and upload the PDF again, I would like for the save button to trigger a post request with the PDF attached.

How can I do this? Is there an Edge setting? Or maybe a javascript code snippet that catches the button?

Comment: thank you for answering me. so you say it is impossible. the only way is for the user to edit, save, download and then upload it again to the server?
I understand the security aspect of it, but from a user perspective it seems kinda silly. There are commercial 3rd party apps that would allow me to do what I want, but they force me to send the PDF via their API to them, then the user can edit it inside their application and then they send it back to me. It's commercial though and I don't want to send all the PDFs somewhere. There gotta be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to the pdf viewer save button to trigger a post request with the PDF attached.

1. The encoded PDF MUST be decoded in the viewers device to be edited into the screen.
   Because of the PDF has been downloaded to the user (even if they dont know they have full ownership of the contents). So, they have full Edit Writes.
2. The thing about PDF is that to save the edits the save function,  however,  in the browser "Save As" is the download button function.
   So, it as device export to filesystem. Their editor is protected against abuse from servers you have ZERO access.

For your requests, we recommend that you could submit a feature request to the Dev Team by sending feedback (Press **Alt+Shift+I**) in Microsoft Edge.